# Adding data into myadminPhp

Tags: mysql

Hey guys so Im trying to add some data into my tables, for some reason the inspection table wouldnt allow to add data to itself. Im uploading it as SQL file because I used mockaroo for dummy data!

```
 /*
-- Use test;
-- Use mysql;
-- Use information_schema;
-- source f:/createempdepttable.sql;
-- Notice the forward slash  / in above statement
*/
-- section 13.1.28. MySQL Documentation DROP TABLE Syntax
Drop database if exists g00337857abu;
create database g00337857abu CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI ;
Use g00337857abu;
Show tables;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoice;

CREATE TABLE  invoice  (
   invoice_no  int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   date  date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(invoice_no)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chauffeurs;

CREATE TABLE  chauffeurs  (
   chauffeur_id  int(10)  NOT NULL,
   fname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   lname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   phone  int(15) NOT NULL,
   address  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   city  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   county  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (chauffeur_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;

CREATE TABLE  customers  (
   customer_id  int(50)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   lname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   address  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   city  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   county  ENUM('Armagh','Carlow','Cavan','Clare','Cork','Derry','Donegal','Down','Dublin','Fermanagh','Galway','Kerry','Kildare','Kilkenny','Laois','Leitrim','Limerick','Longford','Louth','Mayo','Meath','Monaghan','Offaly','Roscommon','Sligo','Tipperary','Tyrone','Waterford','Westmeath','Wexford','Wicklow') NOT NULL,
   phone  int(10) NOT NULL,
   email  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   payment_method  ENUM ('Visa', 'Amex', 'Cash', 'American Express', 'Mastercard') NOT NULL,
   status  ENUM('Approved','Unapproved'),
   driver_no varchar(20),
   PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mechanics;

CREATE TABLE  mechanics  (
   mechanic_id  int(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   lname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (mechanic_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicles;

CREATE TABLE  vehicles (
   vehicle_id  int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   category ENUM('Sedan','Hatchback','SUV', 'Coupe', 'Crossover') NOT NULL,
   no_of_seats  int(11) NOT NULL,
   brand  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   model  varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   product_year  int(11) NOT NULL,
   rate_per_day  int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inspections;

CREATE TABLE  inspections  (
   inspection_id  int(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   inspection_date  date NOT NULL,
   vehicle_id  int(10) NOT NULL,
   problem  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   repair  varchar(55) NOT NULL,
   repair_complete  ENUM('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
   mechanic_id  int(10)  NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(inspection_id),
   KEY mechanic_idfk1 (mechanic_id),
   KEY vehicle_idfk2 (vehicle_id),
   CONSTRAINT vehicle_idfk2 FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicles (vehicle_id),
   CONSTRAINT mechanic_idfk1 FOREIGN KEY (mechanic_id) REFERENCES mechanics (mechanic_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS payment_details;

CREATE TABLE  payment_details  (
   card_no  int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   customer_id  int(50)  NOT NULL,
   CVV  int(11) NOT NULL,
   card_type  ENUM('Visa', 'Amex', 'Cash', 'Mastecard') NOT NULL,
   expiry_date  date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(card_no),
   KEY customer_idfk1 (customer_id),
   CONSTRAINT customer_idfk1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicle_collections;

CREATE TABLE  vehicle_collections  (
   collection_id  int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   vehicle_id  int(10)  NOT NULL,
   collection_date  date NOT NULL,
   return_date  date NOT NULL,
   mileage_before  int(10) NOT NULL,
   mileage_after  int(10) NOT NULL,
   duration  int(5) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (collection_id),
   KEY vehicle_idfk1 (vehicle_id),
   CONSTRAINT vehicle_idfk1 FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicles (vehicle_id)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bookings;

   CREATE TABLE  bookings  (
   booking_id  int(50)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   booking_date  date NOT NULL,
   start_date  date NOT NULL,
   end_date  date NOT NULL,
   invoice_no int(10)  NOT NULL,
   chauffeur_id int(10)NOT NULL,
   vehicle_id int(10)  NOT NULL,
   customer_id int(50) NOT NULL,
   chauffeur_req ENUM('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (booking_id),
   KEY invoice_nofk2 (invoice_no),
   KEY chauffeur_idfk1 (chauffeur_id),
   KEY customer_idfk2 (customer_id),
   KEY vehicle_idfk2 (vehicle_id),
   CONSTRAINT invoice_nofk1 FOREIGN KEY (invoice_no) REFERENCES invoice (invoice_no) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT chauffeur_idfk2 FOREIGN KEY (chauffeur_id) REFERENCES chauffeurs (chauffeur_id)ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT customer_idfk3 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT vehicle_idfk3 FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicles (vehicle_id)ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

error in php is as follows:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`g00337857abu`.`inspections`, CONSTRAINT `mechanic_idfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`mechanic_id`) REFERENCES `mechanics` (`mechanic_id`))

could it be because mechanic table isnt yet filled out? I only filled out chauffeurs customers so far and they were fine

Comment: Basically you cannot add a an inspections row until you have a valid `vehicle` and `mechanics` row already in place because you have a  constraint saying that is impossible

Comment: _Small Note_ `phpMyAdmin` is a too written in PHP and not a database. `MYSQL` is the database

Comment: Ive populated vehicles and mechanics yet I get same error :/

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`g00337857abu`.`inspections`, CONSTRAINT `vehicle_idfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`vehicle_id`))

Comment: Then you have not created a `vehicle` with the id you are using to create the `inspector` row with